# Laravel: Pivot table access in a blade

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm a newbie to Laravel so I'm probably making some sort of noob error. That said, here's my problem.

I'm trying to access a related table from within my blade,. Here are relevant portions of my models:

```
class _MeetingUser extends Model
{
    ...
    public function meeting()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Meetings::class);
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Users::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Meetings extends Model
{
    ...
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Users::class, 'meeting__user');
    }
    ...
```

I have this in my controller:

```
class MeetingController extends Controller
{
    public function edit(Request $request): View
    {
        return view('meetings.edit', [
            'meetings' => Meetings::all(),
            'secretaries' => Users::all(),
        ]);
    ...
```

And my blade has this:

```
             @foreach($meetings as $meeting)
            ...
                        <td><select name="secretaries[]" id="secretaries">
                                <option value="0">Select Secretary</option>
                                @foreach($secretaries as $secretary)
                                    <option value="{{$secretary->id}}"
                                    @if($meeting->users()->id == $secretary->id)
                                        selected="selected"
                                    @endif
                                    >{{$secretary->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </td>
            ...
```

What I tried is detailed above.

What I expect is for the related user id to be selected in my dropdown. When I load the page, I get this:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$id
```

Although I can see it would be wrong, the same thing occurs when I try users_id instead of id.

The pivot table works in the controller. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
This works. But it seems ugly. Isn't there a nice ORM way to do this?

```
  {{  $existing_secretary_id=DB::scalar('select users_id from meeting__user where meetings_id = ?',
                                [$meeting->id]);
                        }}
                        <td><select name="secretaries[]" id="secretaries">
                                <option value="0">Select Secretary</option>
                                @foreach($secretaries as $secretary)
                                    <option value="{{$secretary->id}}"
                                    @if($secretary->id == $existing_secretary_id)
                                        selected="selected"
                                    @endif
                                    >{{$secretary->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </td>
```

Comment: Why are you performing DB query in blade? This should be in your controller/service

Comment: I should be eager loading the data in the controller. But the real problem is that $meeting->users()->id (in the controller or the view) returns the error given above. Whereas this call (in the controller) succeeds: $meeting->users()->syncWithoutDetaching($secretary_id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extensively rewrote this to do eager loading in the controller. As I was working through the process, I realized what the original problem was.

```
@if($meeting->users()->id == $secretary->id)
```

$meeting->users() is a collection. To extract the id, I needed $meeting->users()->first()->id; The problem stemmed from my using a many-to-many relationship between users and meetings (which I want for future changes) and expecting user() to be a single object.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your pivot model name is incorrect. Change the pivot model name to MeetingUser without an underscore. MeetingUser is okay
2. You don't need any relationship in Pivot table. I mean

> ```
> class MeetingUser extends Model
> {
>   // Specify the custom table name for the pivot model.
>   protected $table = "your_db_table_name";
>   ...
> }
> ```

3. Check the correct name of your pivot table in the database; if it's meeting__user, you may want to consider changing it to meeting_users for better convention. If you want to keep the existing name, adjust the relationship in Meetings model like this:

> ```
> class Meetings extends Model
> {
>     ...
>     public function users()
>     {
>         return $this->belongsToMany(Users::class, 'meeting__user','meeting_id','user_id');
>     }
>     ...
> ```
>
> Make sure to make a similar adjustment in the User model.

Comment: The table and model names are as set up for me with artisan create:*. Nonethe less, I refactored the model name as you suggested and added explicit foreign and related keys to the Meetings model, (The table name was already specified by artisan.) I get the same result trying to access *meeting->users()->id. dd($meetings->users)) shows a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany object (the return type of the users() method in the model) with no ID property.

Comment: $meeting->user->id instead of $meeting->users()->id 

and also add 
`public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Users::class);
    }`
to MeetingUser table

Comment: The function already exists in my MeetingUser model. Trying your syntax, I get

'''
Attempt to read property "id" on null
'''